# WPF application crashes

Tags: wpf, crash, locking

There are some crashes in a WPF application and I can not figure out the cause. In development I can not simulate the problem, it occurs only in production and in random situations. The application has several Timers and DispatcherTimers for different processes.

Any suggestions on how to find the locking point? Or at least have some clue where to start analyzing the problem?

Is it possible to know which method is locking the UI thread?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The cause was a flaw in WPF.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33828e1b-224a-4b73-86b5-9af949f07508/installing-net-452-breaks-microsofts-recommended-disablewpftabletsupport-method-for-disabling?forum=wpf

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a much more common situation then you might think.  You have a race condition.  The timing of your application changes in production.

The thing to do is compile your application in release mode with symbols and get the hang to occur on your development machine.  Then you can attach to it with visual studio.  You can then find out how many threads are running and the call stack for each thread.  This might give you insight into what is happening.

If you cannot replicate on your development machine, the next approach is to create a crash dump file.  On the production machine, open the task manager, right click on the application and choose "Create dump file".  This creates a .DMP file that you can move back to the development machine and open with Visual Studio.  You need to have the **exact** symbol files for the application in order for Visual Studio to make heads or tails out of your call stacks.

This will get you started.  Solving these kind of problems is often very difficult and more art than science.  Good luck.